# Material UI Date Range Picker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set up a material ui date range picker example following the code on the docs but it's giving me an error, TypeError: undefined is not a function.

I've never seen useState followed by a component before and it's what's throwing the error.

`React.useState<DateRange>([null, null])`

https://dev.material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/daterangepicker

Complete Code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { DateRangePicker, DateRange, DateRangeDelimiter } from "@material-ui/pickers";

function BasicDateRangePicker() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = React.useState<DateRange>([null, null]);

  return (
    <DateRangePicker
      startText="Check-in"
      endText="Check-out"
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={date => handleDateChange(date)}
      renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
        <>
          <TextField {...startProps} />
          <DateRangeDelimiter> to </DateRangeDelimiter>
          <TextField {...endProps} />
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
}

export default BasicDateRangePicker;
```

Comment: I realized the error was coming from this using TypeScript which I'm not, is there a simple way to convert this to non TypeScript?

Comment: Just remove `<DateRange>` after ``React.useState`.

Comment: Doing that generates a different error " React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports "

Comment: That example is for v4. Are you using `v4.0.0-alpha.7`? Or are you using v3?

Comment: I'm using v4.0.0-alpha.7

Answer (score 4):

Below is a working version. I've added in the `LocalizationProvider` and removed the `<DateRange>` Typescript syntax.

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import {
  DateRangePicker,
  DateRangeDelimiter,
  LocalizationProvider
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import DateFnsUtils from "@material-ui/pickers/adapter/date-fns"; // choose your lib

export default function BasicDateRangePicker() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = React.useState([null, null]);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DateRangePicker
        startText="Check-in"
        endText="Check-out"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={date => handleDateChange(date)}
        renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
          <>
            <TextField {...startProps} />
            <DateRangeDelimiter> to </DateRangeDelimiter>
            <TextField {...endProps} />
          </>
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit DateRangePicker example]

Comment: are you using this in production? I know the website says that there it is not fit for production use, so I'm kinda worried that something untoward might happen

Comment: @foreverAnIntern The v4 alpha (which this question was specifically about) is not considered ready for production use, but v3.2.10 is fine for production use. As part of Material-UI v5, the pickers are moving into `@material-ui/lab` (https://next.material-ui.com/components/date-picker/) and will likely experience some changes to the API while in the lab.

Comment: @ Ryan will refrain from using it then. I need the date range picker, but it appears that material-ui is only making that available through its premium package. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing an error for Mui DateRangePicker with typescript,
"Type 'null[]' is missing the following properties from type 'RangeInput': 0, 1"

latest versions --> "@material-ui/pickers": "^4.0.0-alpha.12" ,
"date-fns": "^2.16.1"

Working code:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField"
import {
  DateRangePicker,
  DateRangeDelimiter,
  LocalizationProvider,
  DateRange,
} from "@material-ui/pickers"
import DateFnsUtils from "@material-ui/pickers/adapter/date-fns"

export default function BasicDateRangePicker() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = React.useState<DateRange<Date | null>>([null, null]);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DateRangePicker
        startText="from"
        endText="to"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={(date: any) => handleDateChange(date)}
        renderInput={(startProps: any, endProps: any) => (
            <>
              <TextField {...startProps} />
              <DateRangeDelimiter> to </DateRangeDelimiter>
              <TextField {...endProps} />
            </>
          )
        }
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DateRangePicker` component also needs the `DateFnsAdapter` and the entire block should be wrapped with `LocalizationProvider`.

Your code should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import DateFnsAdapter from '@material-ui/pickers/adapter/date-fns'; // choose your lib
import { DateRangePicker, DateRange, DateRangeDelimiter, LocalizationProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";


function BasicDateRangePicker() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = React.useState<DateRange>([null, null]);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DateRangePicker
        startText="Check-in"
        endText="Check-out"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={date => handleDateChange(date)}
        renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
          <>
            <TextField {...startProps} />
            <DateRangeDelimiter> to </DateRangeDelimiter>
            <TextField {...endProps} />
          </>
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

export default BasicDateRangePicker;
```

You can read more about the `dateAdapter` in the [quick start](https://dev.material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/usage#quick-start) and in the [installation](https://dev.material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation).

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting an error TypeError: undefined is not a function on ```React.useState<DateRange>([null, null])```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with typescript, VS Code says "Type arguments can only be used in TypeScript files" on <DateRange>. What would be the non typescript version of this?

Comment: What about non typescript version ? is there any ?

Comment: @Omid just remove the `<DateRange>` that you have there after the `useState`.

Comment: this approach is unstable, dont try it

Answer (score -1):

It is not working for me, I have used all alpha versions and it shows this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyboardDate' of undefined

99 |   ...other,
100 |   value,
101 |   onChange,

> 102 |   inputFormat: passedInputFormat || utils.formats.keyboardDate,
> | ^  103 | };
> 104 |
> 105 | const restProps = {

and with the stable version it says it can't find DateRangePicker

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)